# Is there a way to check if a user has rated your app on the app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, rating

I currently have a method that prompts the user to rate my app on the store after the first 20 times they load the app, then the next 30 loads, then the next 40 loads, and so on. The user has 2 options at the UIAlert: RATE NOW or MAYBE LATER. I would really like to avoid annoying the users who have already taken the time to rate the app. Is there a simple way to do this?

Despite the bad form, I'm answering my own question with the best (poor) solution I can manage, so I'm looking for something better than that.

Many thanks to anyone taking the time to think about this one!

Comment: There really is no way to tell if a user has rated your app on the App Store.  There's no identifiable connection between iTunes users and a physical iPhone.

Comment: I am also looking for a way to do this because I found an app called Water Llama (https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1454778585) that does this. When you download the app, you can "unlock a character" in the app, but it only unlocks if you actually leave some kind of rating. If you don't the character does not unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own poor solution:

If the user selects RATE NOW, then never prompt the user again. Otherwise, continue asking on the schedule described.

Problems with this solution:

- The user may not actually submit a review after clicking NOW.
- The user may rate the app independently from my prompting, and I certainly don't want to annoy someone who takes the time to rate it.

Comment: You could add a No thanks button in order to stop annoying a user that doesn't want to rate now or never. This code might be of help: https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/

Comment: Thanks, but the reason for the decreasing frequency is to reduce annoyance. If a user is loading the app 100+ times, then I prefer to ask for a rating.