# How can i know whether the user has rated the app on app store or not

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have a functionality of rate the app in the application on tap of which iTunes link will be opened. I want to award the user with some score when the user rates the app. Is there any way out to know, that the user has rated the app or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318666/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-user-has-rated-your-app-on-the-app-store?rq=1

Comment: Does that means there is no way out to get this?

Comment: Yes, there is no way, as far as i know and the above link says. You can at the max show an alert to rate the app with 2 buttons. Cancel button and Rate button. If user clicks on rate, take user to app store and assume he rated the app (even though user may not) and set a BOOL in user defaults.

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to really check if the user rated your app. You can only do something like a screen to ask for rating and link it to your app in the store. But you will never know if he rated your app after following the link to the store.

Answer (score 0):

Though i have not tested this, just have a look at this that i have found.
 [Here](http://www.binpress.com/app/irate-prompt-users-to-rate-your-app/616)
  [and here](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/)...
Might get some help..

Comment: That are of course cool libraries to get a rating popup which links to the app in the store, but is not the answer to his question. He wants to know if its possible to know if the user rated the app - and the answer for that is NO.