# Check if App is rated in App Store

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, appirater

I have gone through all the links prompted when I was about to post this question.
also this, [Is there a way to check if a user has rated your app on the app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318666/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-user-has-rated-your-app-on-the-app-store)

I want to know if there is any way by which i can know if actually my app has been rated by the user.
P.S: I have used appirater to implement prompt on required event.. which is working properly.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at [AppReviews](https://github.com/gambcl/AppReviews) which queries the app store for reviews.  However be aware that Apple regard these as private APIs, so they may not allow you to query them in an app.

Comment: well Simon thanx but i realy could not understand AppReviews use for my purpose or may be it is but i cant get it. i Got dat it is able to retrieve app from app ID  and select its main region.but how can i check if the user who has downloaded the app has also written the review on app store..there are private APIs as u correctly pointed but do you know wether apple allows dis in iOS or not? i suppose Android allows dis check!! thanx

Comment: Ah, I see - no, I don't think there's a way to tie the phone to the app store user.